# Как сделать div блок прозрачным

Tags: jquery, css, html5

[image]

Вот как на изображений,только в черном блоке было все размыто (то есть за ним) что бы на этот блок можно было ещё текст наложить и картинки (без размытия )

Можно как нибудь это осуществить в css или JQure ?

к слову Задний фон в классе `body`

Comment: Подсказка: внутрь дива поместить эту же картинку, но со смещением, чтоб казалось будто он прозрачный и уже на него `filter: blur()`. А так, не существует css свойств для размытия картинки позади дива.

Comment: поддерживаю выше сказанное! Установить одинаковый фон , Фон квадрату я задавал фиксированным
`background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
filter: blur(3px); `

Comment: @MishaSaidov "_А так, не существует css свойств для размытия картинки позади дива_" Я и [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backdrop-filter) с Вами не согласны. Загвоздка в том, что не каждый юзер догадается/осмелится включить в настройках необходимый флажок (в Хроме, например - chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features). Хотя, в Safari и Edge уже включено по умолчанию. При включенном флажке можно посмотреть на [красоту](https://codepen.io/jeremy-hewitt/pen/mGPVRe)

Comment: @UModeL Я видимо жёстко отстал от индустрии, не стоит больше позволять себе такие смелые высказывания)

Comment: @MishaSaidov отстанешь тут - уже сколько лет поддержку backdrop-filter не могут реализовать. Уже и не надеется никто))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так?

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto
}
.wrapper .text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px)
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThkkP.jpg"/>
  <div class="text">Какой-то текст</div>
</div>
```

Но с поддержкой так себе

Есть вариант с svg-filter [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/iamvdo/pen/VLOGdw)